# Is it possible to assign formControlName dynamiclally based on api response in angular10?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an `angular` `reactive` form in which i have a scenario in which i have to assign `formControlName` conditionally based on `api response`.

I have form field like this

```
 <input type="number" min="0" [formControlName]="amountControl" class="form-control" placeholder="Bid Amount">
```

component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
  getApiData()
}

getApiData(){
 // all code goes here. 
   this.masterObj.paymentTerms = response.paymentTerms;
}

get amountControl(): string {
  if(this.masterObj)
   {
     return this.masterObj.paymentTems == "On Credit" ? 'bidAmountCredit' : 'bidAmount'
   }
  else return "";
```

}

Now the scenario is that if in the api response the `this.masterObj?.paymentTerms` value will be `On Credit` so i have to assign `bidAmountCredit` as `formControlName` but if i will have `this.masterObj?.paymentTerms` value will be `Cash` so i have to assign the `formControlName` as `bidAmount`

Currently it always assigning `bidAmount` as `formControlNaem`

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a get method from Typescript

```
get formName(): string {
   if(this.masterObj)
    {
      return this.masterObj.paymentTems == "On Credit" ? 'bidAmountCredit' : 'bidAmount'
    }
    else return "";
}
```

Then, you use it as a variable

```
<input type="number" min="0" [formControlName]="formName" class="form-control" placeholder="Bid Amount">
```

This can help you also in better debugging what is happening with the condition.

Comment: same problem. It is still assigning `bidAmount`. See my updated question post

Comment: What does it shows if you do a console.log(this.masterObj.paymentTems) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use formControl input.

Let's suppose that form is the reference to your formGroup (inside ts file)

You can assign formControl like this:

```
<input type="number" min="0" [formControl]="form.controls[amountControl]" class="form-control" placeholder="Bid Amount">
```